# My first Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am new to Unit Testing and just created a one small test for my word ladder function.

Can anyone pls advise if it looks okay and if it is a right way of doing it?

Also, is there a way to add a test to current project indtead of creating a sepereate Unit Test project in VS2012?

```
[TestMethod()]
public void MyFirstUnitTest()
{
    string f = "hit";
    string s = "cat";
    string test= "";
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    test = wordLadder (wordList, f, s);
    test = lst.ToArray;
    Assert.IsTrue(test == "hit,hat,cat");
}
```

Comment: As it stands, that won’t compile. But otherwise (assuming just typos there), it looks somewhat fine. You should be using `Assert.AreEqual` instead though. Also, VS should recognize all tests that live in a public class with `[TestClass]`, regardless of project type.

Comment: i get this error 'TestClass' cannot be used as an attribute because it does not inherit from 'System.Attribute' if i add method to new class in the same project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UnitTests are basically said to be composed of three parts: `Arrange`, `Act` and `Assert`

We can clearly see all three parts there, being

#### Arrange

```
string f = "hit";
string s = "cat";
string test= "";
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
```

#### Act

```
test = wordLadder (wordList, f, s);
```

#### Assert

```
Assert.IsTrue(test == "hit,hat,cat");
```

However, the points I would highlight are:

1. Do not name variables `f`, `s` or any other names which are not intuitive to people who will be reading the test in future.
2. Do not name your test method as `MyFirstUnitTest`. The method name should at least expose what the method is in fact testing
3. What is `wordList`? Where is it defined?
4. Finally, `Assert.IsTrue(test == "hit,hat,cat");` is not the right approach. You basically will want to use that when testing some boolean returned value. To test a given value against an expected value, use `Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)`

Take a look at this excelent piece of article for some information that might be useful ([Link](https://www.toptal.com/qa/how-to-write-testable-code-and-why-it-matters))

Comment: do i have to create a untiTest class in sepereate project? Can it be added in exisiting project?

Comment: In `C#` it is usually put in a different project. Take a look at unit testing basics https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694602.aspx

Comment: @user1263981 - see my added comment just now. Always create a separate project(s)! Ideally 1 unit test project for every project in your solution.

Comment: @user1263981 Yes, put it in a different project; you don't want to bloat the deployed library or application with unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You get the idea, here is your code (but modified so it will actually compile and pass the unit test).

Split your unit test methods into 3 sections (*aka the 3 As*):

- Arrange - get your data ready so you can test some method
- Act - execute the test
- Assert - validate the results of the test

Code:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyFirstUnitTest()
    {
        // arrange
        string f = "hit";
        string s = "cat";

        // act - this is not a great example of why to unit test but you had nothing in the OP that would compile so we are testing the output of string.Join
        List<string> lst = new List<string>(){f, "hat", s};
        var test = string.Join(",", lst);

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(test, "hit,hat,cat"); // you can append a 3rd boolean parameter if you care about case sensitivity
    }
}
```

One final comment which I think is self evident but as you are new to unit testing in .net maybe it is not to you. Always create a separate project(s) for your unit tests. Each type that you are testing should also be tested in a separate unit test file (so new unit test class type). In your example above you are referencing `wordLadder` and `wordList` which leads me to believe that maybe you have included a unit test inside your actual type that you are wanting to test which is a huge no-no as you want to completely isolate the unit test code from the actual code that will compile into your end product.

See also [MSDN - Unit Test Basics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694602.aspx) and [Arrange Act Assert](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert).

Comment: So, you’re testing `string.Join`?

Comment: @poke - in this instance I am as the OP did not have anything that would compile.

Comment: Thank you. The wordLadder function is in Main project which is not a part of Unti Test project but i had to include the Read File function into Unti Test class which read external word list file.